# Visual Studio Code: Keyboard shortcut for instance type

Tags: apex, visualstudiocode, developer-productivity

I want to get the type of an instance autofilled in VSCode based on its declaration, as in, typing:

```
List<Account> lsAcc = new
```

And then use a keyboard shortcut to get the default:

```
List<Account>();
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Salesforce Extension Pack (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode) you should also get the following auto-completion for `Map`, `List` and `Set` through the Apex language features.

[image: lsAcc-Demo]

Granted, you have to slightly change the way you write your List initialisations, but for me this feature has proven to be a way more convenient way of doing this over and over again!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, more or less, by writing a [custom snippet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_create-your-own-snippets)

> You can easily define your own snippets without any extension. To create or edit your own snippets, select User Snippets under File > Preferences (Code > Preferences on macOS), and then select the language (by language identifier) for which the snippets should appear, or the New Global Snippets file option if they should appear for all languages. VS Code manages the creation and refreshing of the underlying snippets file(s) for you.

It's probably not going to be a 100% match for you, but the end result might be even better.

You could start typing something like `list`, hit ctrl + space, and then using a single tabstop identifier (i.e. `$0`) in multiple locations you can make it so that you only need to type out the type once.